# How to get the value of href using text

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following text: 'abcdef' ,
I want to use this text to get the href. How can I do it?

```
<span class="thumb_link">
    <a class="link_txt" href="/14803/tool/4554"> abcdef</a>
</span>
```

I tried the following but it failed

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[text()="abcdef"]')
```

Because the matching point is text, it must be obtained using text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link text would do that or if you have several similar link texts. Another way is with xpath.

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='abcdef']").get_attribute("href")

Answer (score 1):

Selenium's link text allows you to do that.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("abcdef").get_attribute("href")
```

will return the href.